# Select RDF collection/list and iterate result with Jena

Tags: list, rdf, resultset, sparql, jena

For some RDF like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:blah="http://www.something.org/stuff#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.something.org/stuff/some_entity1">
<blah:stringid>string1</blah:stringid>
<blah:uid>1</blah:uid>
<blah:myitems rdf:parseType="Collection">
  <blah:myitem>
        <blah:myitemvalue1>7</blah:myitemvalue1>
        <blah:myitemvalue2>8</blah:myitemvalue2>
     </blah:myitem>
...
    <blah:myitem>
     <blah:myitemvalue1>7</blah:myitemvalue1>
        <blah:myitemvalue2>8</blah:myitemvalue2>
    </blah:myitem>
</blah:myitems>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.something.org/stuff/some__other_entity2">
<blah:stringid>string2</blah:stringid>
<blah:uid>2</blah:uid>
<blah:myitems rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <blah:myitem>
        <blah:myitemvalue1>7</blah:myitemvalue1>
        <blah:myitemvalue2>8</blah:myitemvalue2>
     </blah:myitem>
....
    <blah:myitem>
        <blah:myitemvalue1>7</blah:myitemvalue1>
        <blah:myitemvalue2>8</blah:myitemvalue2>
    </blah:myitem>
</blah:myitems>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I'm using Jena/SPARQL and I'd like to be able to use a SELECT query to retrieve the `myitems` node for an entity with a particular `stringid` and then extract it from the resultset and iterate through and get the values for each `myitem` nodes. Order isn't important.

So I have two questions:

1. Do I need to specify in my query that `blah:myitems` is a list?
2. How can I parse a list in a ResultSet?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to _do_ with the elements of the list?  Depending on what you want to do, it might be easier to pull all the elements out from the SPARQL query and then just iterate over the result set, rather than selecting the list and then processing it afterward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Selecting Lists (and Elements) in SPARQL

Let's address the SPARQL issue first.  I've modified your data just a little bit so that the elements have different values, so it will be easier to see them in the output.  Here's the data in N3 format, which is a bit more concise, especially when representing lists:

```
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix blah:    <http://www.something.org/stuff#> .

<http://www.something.org/stuff/some_entity1>
      blah:myitems ([ a       blah:myitem ;
                  blah:myitemvalue1 "1" ;
                  blah:myitemvalue2 "2"
                ] [ a       blah:myitem ;
                  blah:myitemvalue1 "3" ;
                  blah:myitemvalue2 "4"
                ]) ;
      blah:stringid "string1" ;
      blah:uid "1" .

<http://www.something.org/stuff/some__other_entity2>
      blah:myitems ([ a       blah:myitem ;
                  blah:myitemvalue1 "5" ;
                  blah:myitemvalue2 "6"
                ] [ a       blah:myitem ;
                  blah:myitemvalue1 "7" ;
                  blah:myitemvalue2 "8"
                ]) ;
      blah:stringid "string2" ;
      blah:uid "2" .
```

You mentioned in the question selecting the `myitems` node, but `myitems` is actually the *property* that relates the entity to the list.   You can select properties in SPARQL, but I'm guessing that you actually want to select the head of the list, i.e., the value of the `myitems` property.  That's straightforward.  You don't need to specify that it's an `rdf:List`, but if the value of `myitems` could also be a non-list, then you should specify that you're only looking for `rdf:Lists`.  (For developing the SPARQL queries, I'll just run them using Jena's ARQ command line tools, because we can move them to the Java code easily enough afterward.)

```sql
prefix blah: <http://www.something.org/stuff#> 

select ?list where { 
  [] blah:myitems ?list .
}
```

```
$ arq --data data.n3 --query items.sparql
--------
| list |
========
| _:b0 |
| _:b1 |
--------
```

The heads of the lists are blank nodes, so this is the sort of result that we're expecting.  From these results, you could get the resource from a result set and then start walking down the list, but since you don't care about the order of the nodes in the list, you might as well just select them in the SPARQL query, and then iterate through the result set, getting each item.  It also seems likely that you might be interested in the entity whose items you're retrieving, so that's in this query too.

```sql
prefix blah:    <http://www.something.org/stuff#> 
prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?entity ?list ?item ?value1 ?value2 where { 
  ?entity blah:myitems ?list .
  ?list rdf:rest* [ rdf:first ?item ] .
  ?item a blah:myitem ;
        blah:myitemvalue1 ?value1 ;
        blah:myitemvalue2 ?value2 .
}
order by ?entity ?list
```

```
$ arq --data data.n3 --query items.sparql
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| entity                                               | list | item | value1 | value2 |
========================================================================================
| <http://www.something.org/stuff/some__other_entity2> | _:b0 | _:b1 | "7"    | "8"    |
| <http://www.something.org/stuff/some__other_entity2> | _:b0 | _:b2 | "5"    | "6"    |
| <http://www.something.org/stuff/some_entity1>        | _:b3 | _:b4 | "3"    | "4"    |
| <http://www.something.org/stuff/some_entity1>        | _:b3 | _:b5 | "1"    | "2"    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

By ordering the results by entity and by list (in case some entity has multiple values for the `myitems` property), you can iterate through the result set and be assured of getting, in order, all the elements in a list for an entity.  Since your question was about lists in result sets, and not about how to work with result sets, I'll assume that iterating through the results isn't a problem.

### Working with Lists in Jena

The following example shows how you can work with lists in Java.  The first part of the code is just the boilerplate to load the model and run the SPARQL query.  Once you're getting the results of the query back, you can either treat the resource as the head of a linked list and use the `rdf:first` and `rdf:rest` properties to iterate manually, or you can cast the resource to Jena's `RDFList` and get an iterator out of it.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFList;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;

public class SPARQLListExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create a model and load the data
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        try ( InputStream in = SPARQLListExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "SPARQLListExampleData.rdf" ) ) {
            model.read( in, null );
        }
        String blah = "http://www.something.org/stuff#";
        Property myitemvalue1 = model.createProperty( blah + "myitemvalue1" );
        Property myitemvalue2 = model.createProperty( blah + "myitemvalue2" );

        // Run the SPARQL query and get some results
        String getItemsLists = "" +
                "prefix blah: <http://www.something.org/stuff#>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "select ?list where {\n" +
                "  [] blah:myitems ?list .\n" +
                "}";
        ResultSet results = QueryExecutionFactory.create( getItemsLists, model ).execSelect();

        // For each solution in the result set
        while ( results.hasNext() ) {
            QuerySolution qs = results.next();
            Resource list = qs.getResource( "list" ).asResource();
            // Once you've got the head of the list, you can either process it manually 
            // as a linked list, using RDF.first to get elements and RDF.rest to get 
            // the rest of the list...
            for ( Resource curr = list;
                  !RDF.nil.equals( curr );
                  curr = curr.getRequiredProperty( RDF.rest ).getObject().asResource() ) {
                Resource item = curr.getRequiredProperty( RDF.first ).getObject().asResource();
                RDFNode value1 = item.getRequiredProperty( myitemvalue1 ).getObject();
                RDFNode value2 = item.getRequiredProperty( myitemvalue2 ).getObject();
                System.out.println( item+" has:\n\tvalue1: "+value1+"\n\tvalue2: "+value2 );
            }
            // ...or you can make it into a Jena RDFList that can give you an iterator
            RDFList rdfList = list.as( RDFList.class );
            ExtendedIterator<RDFNode> items = rdfList.iterator();
            while ( items.hasNext() ) {
                Resource item = items.next().asResource();
                RDFNode value1 = item.getRequiredProperty( myitemvalue1 ).getObject();
                RDFNode value2 = item.getRequiredProperty( myitemvalue2 ).getObject();
                System.out.println( item+" has:\n\tvalue1: "+value1+"\n\tvalue2: "+value2 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```